# Location object Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got a php file inside this folder structure:

Web -> script -> gen.php

From this gen.php I want to redirect with the `location()` function in Javascript to

Web->Index.html

I tried to do it like this:

```
location = "localhost/Web/index.html"
```

But I only get a `404 error` saying that this path is invalid. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You need to specify the protocol. `location = "http://localhost/Web/index.html"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`location`, in JavaScript, is not a function. It is a property that you can assign a value to.

Any of (assuming Web is exposed on the URL and isn't just an internal directory):

- `http://localhost/Web/index.html`
- `//localhost/Web/index.html`
- `/Web/index.html`
- `index.html`

However, redirects should usually be handled with HTTP, so you are likely better off with:

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://localhost/Web/index.html');
    exit;
?>
```

(Note that while most browsers will recover from a relative URI in the location header, the specification requires an absolute URI).

Answer (score 2):

write `location = "http://localhost/Web/index.html"` instead. you missed to add `http://`

OR `location = "index.html"` if you are in the same directory